# Unable to run node.js app through Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a node.js application which I am trying to run in docker.  Here is the package.json file snippet.

```
"main": "lib/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "cross-env rm -rf dist",
    "build": "cross-env babel lib -d dist",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run serve",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon lib/server.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js lib/ scripts/ --ignore-pattern node_modules/"
  }
```

And here is the Dockerfile to build the image

```
#---- Base Node------
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY lib ./lib

RUN npm install --only=production && npm run build

EXPOSE 4201

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

I get the following error when I try to run the image. Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

The node and npm version are the same on my machine and the base image that I am using to build my image.
When I run the same command locally in my machine it works
Here is the exact command that I am running on my machine and it works.

> npm install --only=production
>
> npm run build
>
> npm run serve

Am I doing something wrong here ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check your `package.json` dependency list, you might not have added `express` in it. Post full `package.json` file.

Comment: Are you sure Babel is available and transpiling successfully?

Comment: `"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",`
    `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",`
    `"express": "^4.16.4"`
Yes I have babel and express. How do I check if babel is transpiling successfully ?

Comment: Found it. I forgot to copy .babelrc in the Dockerfile to the workspace. It should have  been this `COPY .babelrc ./` . 
.babelrc is required for babel to transpile.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ES6 imports

> import x from package

In order to do that, you should have Babel package installed, otherwise it won't know how to import that file

Comment: `"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",`
    `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",`
    `"express": "^4.16.4"`
Yes I have babel installed.